# Как поставить вызовы асинхронной ф-ии в очередь, и не чаще 3 в секунду?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, асинхронность

Асинхронная ф-я может вызываться из разных мест большого кода, с передачей коллбэка для возврата результата.

Есть ограничение: нельзя вызывать эту ф-ю чаще 3 раз в секунду.

Не могу сообразить, как проще сделать очередь задач.

Сделал два буфера: массив времён последних трёх вызовов `times` и массив объектов заданий `tasks`, где каждый содержит параметры вызова и callback.

Перед выполнением очередного вызова необходимая задержка определяется как неотрицательная разность текущего времени c моментом `times[0]`. После выполнения вызова, текущее время заносится в хвост: `times.push(ts); times = times.slice(-3)`.

Ф-я вызывается с необх. таймаутом либо по поступлении первого объекта в пустую очередь, либо по завершении очередного задания из очереди.

Есть ли в каком-нибудь JS фреймворке похожий функционал, чтобы списать, и правильно ли я подхожу к задаче перестроения асинхронных вызовов в последовательность?

```
App.timeSpan = 1000;
App.times = [];
App.tasks = [];

// точка входа
App.api = function( method, params, callback) {
    var toWait, dt, ts = (new Date()).getTime();

    this.tasks.push({
        method: method,
        params: params,
        callback: callback
    });

    if( this.tasks.length == 1) {
        if( this.times.length > 2) {
            dt = ts - this.times[0];
            toWait = ( dt < this.timeSpan) ? this.timeSpan - dt : 0;
        } else {
            toWait = 0;
        }
        window.setTimeout(this.execute.bind(this), toWait);
    }
}

App.execute = function(){
    if( this.tasks.length == 0) return;

    // вызов ТОЙ ф-ии
    VK.api( this.tasks[0].method, this.tasks[0].params, this.executed.bind(this));
}

App.executed = function(r){
    var ts = (new Date()).getTime() // timestamp in seconds
        ,dt
        ,toWait
    ;

    this.times.push( ts);
    this.times = this.times.slice(-3);

    if( this.times.length > 2) {
        dt = ts - this.times[0];
        toWait = ( dt < this.timeSpan) ? this.timeSpan - dt : 0;
    } else {
        toWait = 0;
    }

    if( this.tasks.length > 1) {
        window.setTimeout(this.execute.bind(this), toWait);
    }

    this.tasks.shift().callback.call(this, r);
}
```

Comment: `500` – костыль на случай ошибки подсчета времени на том конце: «чтобы наверняка» не поспешить. Убрал отвлекающие костыли.

Comment: @shatal мне кажется, вы не поняли вопрос. Если будет понятнее «на пальцах», то речь про приложение, обращающееся к api внешнего сервиса, у которого стоит ограничение на частоту вызовов: не более 3 в 1 секунду. Иначе вместо ожидаемого ответа вернётся ошибка. Вызовы к api нужны повсюду: и при заходе показать аватар юзера, и выполнить полезную нагрузку, и получить многостраничный список объектов (каждая стр. – новый вызов api). В любом случае, я уже разобрался.

Comment: Про очередь и в вопросе написано, про «несанкционированно» вам, наверное, показалось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему, радикально упростить код не получится. Получилось лишь сделать его чуть более "красивым":

```js
//for tests
function mock(m, p, callback) {
    var time = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(m + ' ' + p);
    }, time);
}

//for tests
function callbackMock(r) {
   console.log("Callbacked: " + r);
}

function App() { }

App.callsPerTimeSpan = 3;
App.timeSpan = 1000;
App.times = [];
App.tasks = [];
App.handling = false;
App.taskHandler = mock; //mock - for tests

App.api = function(method, params, callback) {
    this.tasks.push({
        method: method,
        params: params,
        callback: callback
    });
    if (!this.handling) {
        this.handling = true;
        this.execute();
    }
};

App.execute = function() {
    if (this.tasks.length == 0) {
        this.handling = false;
        return;
    }
    var toWait = 0;
    if (this.times.length == this.callsPerTimeSpan) {
        var ts = this.getCurrentTime();
        var dt = ts - this.times[0];
        toWait = (dt < this.timeSpan) ? this.timeSpan - dt : 0;
    }
    var task = this.tasks[0];
    var that = this;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        that.taskHandler(task.method, task.params, that.executed.bind(that));
    }, toWait);
};

App.executed = function(r) {
    var ts = this.getCurrentTime();
    this.times.push(ts);
    this.times = this.times.slice(-this.callsPerTimeSpan);
    var task = this.tasks.shift();
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        task.callback.call(that, r);
    }, 0); //async call
    this.execute();
};

App.getCurrentTime = function() {
    return (new Date()).getTime();
};

//for tests
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    App.api(String.fromCharCode(i + 65), i, callbackMock);
}
```

"Красота" в первую очередь включает в себя отсутствующий дублированный код расчета времени и исполнения следующей задачи.

[Пример с выводом отладочной информации в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gterdx0w/).

Comment: Спасибо за ясность! Вопрос: почему безопаснее держать флаг, чем считать кол-во задач в очереди? Ведь уйти из очереди они могут только по завершении выполнения.

Comment: Так ведь JS не параллелится, всё в один тред (про web workers молчим!). Если начал выполняться `.executed()`, никакой другой кусок кода не стартанёт, пока не доиграет `.shift()`, и в `tasks` не станет 0.

Comment: @Sergiks никогда, как говорится, не поздно узнать, что в JS поток должен выполниться полностью, прежде чем запустится другой. Теперь я это узнал :) У флага, в таком случае, остаётся лишь одно преимущество: он является чуть более гибким решением, чем сравнение с константой длины массива. Но это опять-таки имеет смысл, только если что-то в логике коде может поменяться. Про безопасность из ответа уберу.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли в каком-нибудь JS фреймворке похожий функционал

Есть. В jQuery точно есть [throttle и debounce](http://habrahabr.ru/post/60957/), в других тоже что-то похожее. Вообще, гуглится замечательно. Да и реализуется несложно. Например, [вот](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce/blob/master/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.js) расширенная версия с комментариями.

---

> там «проглатываются» лишние вызовы функции. В моей задаче этого нельзя допускать

Тогда так:

```
function queue(f, ms) {
  var calls = null;

  return function () {
    if (calls == null) {
      calls = [];
      setTimeout(function go() { // Гарантируем асинхронный вызов
        if (calls.length) {
          f.apply(null, calls.shift())
          setTimeout(go, ms);
        } else {
          calls = null;
        }
      });
    }

    calls.push(arguments);
  }
}
```

Проверка:

```
f = queue(function () { console.log(new Date, arguments) }, 1000)
f(1); f(1, 2); f({});
setTimeout(f, 3500);
setTimeout(f, 4500, [4, 5], "q");
setTimeout(f, 6000, 6);
setTimeout(f, 8000, 8);
setTimeout(f, 8500, 8.5);
setTimeout(f, 9000, 9);
setTimeout(f, 11000, 9);
```

Comment: `throttle()` и `debounce()` мне знакомы по `underscore.js` – там «проглатываются» лишние вызовы функции. В моей задаче этого нельзя допускать.

Comment: Т. е. нужны все вызовы, но с задержкой в 3s? Это же ещё проще.

Comment: @Sergiks, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Два условия в вопросе: 1. Нужно делать не больше 3 запросов в секунду. 2. Нужно делать следующий запрос только после выполнения предыдущего.

Comment: @Regent, теперь понял. Функция асинхронная, нужно дождаться коллбека и только после этого слать запрос. Причём с интервалом не меньше 334ms. Значит сохраняем время вызова, ждём (перехватываем) коллбек, после чего ставим таймер на оставшееся время. Потом напишу.

Comment: Интервал между запросами может быть и меньше 334 миллисекунд :) Главное, чтобы в любое "окно" из 1000 миллисекунд попадало не более трёх запросов. То есть запросы с timestamp `3ms, 90ms, 200ms, 1005ms, 1100ms` - это нормально, а `3ms, 90ms, 200ms, 1005ms, 1050ms` уже плохо, так как `90`, `200`, `1005` и `1050` попадают в одно секундное окно. Например, в `89 - 1088`.

Comment: @Regent, я понял. Но мне кажется, что равномерная посылка удобнее. Либо, можно с интервалом в 1 секунду посылать цепочки из трёх запросов. Любая такая задача может быть сведена к варианту с равными интервалами.