# Узнать контекст вызова в Node.js

Tags: node.js

Можно ли узнать и вернуть данные в контекст, или может это можно сделать иначе, есть асинхронный код обращения к LDAP . если его вызвать пока не закочен предыдущий запрос то он падает, собственно решение проблемы вижу в создании объекта eventemitter.on который будет создавать пул, то есть если туда придут данные пока прошлый запрос не окончен то данные будут кидаться в массив из которого ф-ция запроса будет их брать при окончании запроса к LDAP, обратно данные будут браться по динамически создаваемому eventemitter.on(уникальный ID) . проблему вижу в пложении eventemitter'ов и при большом кол-ве запросов будет жор памяти, ну и + надо будет увеличивать defaultMaxListeners, может есть какое более адекватное решение этой проблемы ????

Answer (score 1):

Можно сохранить массив колбеков, которые потом вызывать.

Клд будет аналогичен [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436097/178988), только надо перехватывать вызов коллбека и тогда уже делать следующий запрос.

Comment: не очень понятно как складывать калбэки в массив